# Should we invest in Apple?

Tags: plotting, legending, curated-data, date-and-time, finance

```
Ticker[comp_String] := 
 Interpreter["Company"][comp] /. Entity[_, x_] :> x

ticks = Ticker /@ {"Apple", "Google"}
```

> {"NASDAQ:AAPL", "NASDAQ:GOOGL"}

```
DateListPlot[{
  FinancialData[ticks[[1]],  "CumulativeFractionalChange", {2010}],
  FinancialData[ticks[[2]],  "CumulativeFractionalChange", {2010}],
  FinancialData["NASDAQ100", "CumulativeFractionalChange", {2010}]
  },
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> {ticks[[1]], ticks[[2]], "NASDAQ100"},
 Joined -> True,
 ImageSize -> 500,
 Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

I have many questions, but only pose two:

(1) How can I efficiently apply  a moving average of , let's say, 200 days to the above lines?

(2) How can I sort the `PlotLegends`? (NASDAQ100  should appear before NASDAQ:GOOGL)

Comment: Have you looked at InteractiveTradingChart[]. It has many of the features found on professional trading platforms.

Comment: It depends on the [weather](http://www.opb.org/news/article/npr-apple-farmers-scramble-to-save-last-of-their-fruit/).

Comment: I think [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAG39jKi0lI) answers the title. Should I post an answer?

Comment: @belisarius Please post, and I will immediately accept it :)

Comment: So, finally, should we?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using mathematica v10

```
ticks = TemporalData@
 FinancialData[#,"CumulativeFractionalChange", {2010}] & /@ {"AAPL", "^NDX","GOOGL"};
maticks = MovingAverage[#, 200] & /@ ticks;
DateListPlot[{ticks, maticks}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"AAPL", "^NDX", "GOOGL", "MA(200)-AAPL", 
   "MA(200)-^NDX", "MA(200)-GOOGL"}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> Bottom, 2 -> Bottom, 3 -> Bottom}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Red, 
    Black}, {{Dashed, Blue}, {Dashed, Red}, {Dashed, Black}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
fdata = FinancialData[#, "CumulativeFractionalChange", {{2009, 1, 1}, {2014, 11, 1}}] & /@
       {"NASDAQ:AAPL", "NASDAQ:GOOGL", "NASDAQ100"};

ma200 = FinancialIndicator["WildersMovingAverage", 200] /@ fdata[[All, All, 2]];
madata = Transpose[{fdata[[1, All, 1]], Join[ConstantArray[Missing[], 199], #]}] & /@ ma200;

DateListPlot[Join[fdata, madata],  Joined -> {False, False, False, True, True, True}, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}]],
 BaseStyle -> Thick, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, {"NASDAQ:AAPL", "NASDAQ:GOOGL", "NASDAQ100"},
   LegendLayout -> (Grid[#[[{1, 3, 2}]]] &)]]
```

[image]