# How to plot market share data in standard form

Tags: plotting

I am trying to accomolish exactly this (not related to market but with exactly same representation):

[image: market share example]

Is there any special function in mathematica to do these types of plots? Or how would you suggest to implement this if it is not possible directly in plot functions?

I guess that I will have to resample the data to common grid first then plot sum of all, then all but one, two, etc. and overlay them.

Comment: That's how I would do it. You should try it! Otherwise, without more details about the format of the data, it's hard to help. But look at the option Filling for Plot and ListLinePlot and friends.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: See [Stacked Line Graph with fragmented data](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47069/stacked-line-graph-with-fragmented-data) and [FinancialData](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialData.html) and [Should we invest in Apple?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65631/should-we-invest-in-apple)

Comment: Thank you! [Stacked Line Graph with fragmented data](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47069/stacked-line-graph-with-fragmented-data) is the one I was looking for. This question should be marked as duplicate